# Facebook Create New App Error - "should not contain protocol information."

Tags: facebook

I am trying to update/create my app's "app domain" but it keeps throwing this error:

> Error
>
> App Domains: http://www.example.com should not contain protocol information.

Whereas I am 100% sure that my website doesn't have any OpenGraph meta tags.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Remove the `http://` part

Try only `www.example.com` or just `example.com`.

It worked for me.

Comment: thanks. but no, it doesn't work. this time it gives me a:

"Error
You have specified an App Domains but have not specified a Site URL or a Mobile Site URL
mywebsite.com must be derived from your Site URL or your Mobile Site URL."

Comment: Well then specify one of those two first … The error messages are quite clear and straight-forward – what’s your actual problem with understanding them?

Comment: @IamNoobiesh I think you are misinterpreting the original error. When it refers to protocol information, it's talking about the "http://" part of the URL

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `http://` I had the same problem, Initially I used to enter http://www.example.com and facebook caused error. But when I used just [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) by removing `http://` it worked.

Also if you are not using secure server like `https://`, you need to tick sandbox and specity url in mobile native too.

Answer (score 0):

Hello you may have been mixed up the fields `protocol name` and `site url`.
Just like this :
`site url` field should have `http://`
and `protocol information` field shouldn't have `http://`

Regards, Mutlu.

Answer (score -1):

I recently went through the Facebook app creation , even i faced that problem .

But i got success , if i didn't put the "App Domains:" domain value under "Basic Info".

SO you don't need to put the "App Domain " value instead of that you have to fill the value only for below requirement as per your requirement

1. Website with Facebook Login [Mandatory]
2. App on Facebook
3. Page Tab