# Facebook error: Site URL must use the HTTP or HTTPS protocols

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I just created an app on facebook, my first time. I'm getting an error in the Basic Information. I got

`Site URL must use the HTTP or HTTPS protocols.`

I'm inputting "mysite.com" as said in the tutorial https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started/ i also tried inputting "www.mysite.com". I tried to input something like "http://mysite.com/" but I get the two errors displayed like this:

`Error App Domains: http://mysite.com/ should not contain protocol information. Site URL must use the HTTP or HTTPS protocols.`

What do I need to do here? I also tried the suggested answer in this [Facebook Create New App Error - "should not contain protocol information."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507582/facebook-create-new-app-error-should-not-contain-protocol-information), but still getting either both or one of the two errors above.

Comment: It might help if you added your actual domain name to the question, so that we could verify that it works correctly.

Comment: hi @Martey i have edited the question a

Comment: It looks like @bernd-ott removed it because he thought it was advertising...

Comment: In review panel i didn't saw the request for it in comments. it looked like "i add quick a domain to get more hits". I can't rollback my changes (i get an error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you are getting ("Site URL must use the HTTP or HTTPS protocols.") does not relate to the App Domain, but to the Site URL (in the "Website with Facebook Login" section).

While the App Domain must not have its protocol (HTTP or HTTPS) included, the Site URL should. See: [image: partial screenshot of Facebook App creation screen]